# Add another logo in right lower corner in the Overleaf's Berkeley theme

Tags: beamer, overleaf, logos

I am trying to modify Beamer's [Berkeley theme](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uc-berkeley-beamer-theme/bywswngntrws). I'd like to have the oblique blue line at the bottom of each slide to break in the middle of the slide and insert in a mirror another logo over a white background. Unfortunately, I am not that skilled with such complex LaTeX code.

Comment: I don't have, or want, an Overleaf account. If there were a way for me to access the theme without one, I might try to help. I urge Overleaf users to complain about its reckless profileration of packages not on CTAN. That's harmful to the LaTeX ecosystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `beamerthemeUCBerkeley.sty`, search for `\setbeamertemplate{background}` and replace that with this code.

```tex
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[BerkeleyBlue] (current page.south west) -- +(0, 0.18\paperheight) -- +(0.5*\paperwidth, 0.08\paperheight) -- (current page.south) -- cycle;
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt,draw=none,xshift=0.055\paperheight,yshift=0.04\paperheight] at (current page.south west) {\pgfuseimage{logo}};%

% 2nd logo
\node[anchor=south east, inner sep=5pt, xshift=-0.055\paperheight, yshift=0.04\paperheight, fill=BerkeleyBlue] at (current page.south east) {\pgfuseimage{logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Output:

[image]

You can adjust `xshift` and `yshift` in the 2nd logo to place it as you like. The `inner sep` setting controls the padding between the logo and its fill border.

Comment: Zxcvasdf, could you please help again with this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649456/change-beamer-logo-during-the-presentation?noredirect=1#comment1618599_649456? Thank you in advance :)