# How to change Beamer logo during the presentation

Tags: beamer, overleaf, logos

My previous question has been [solved](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648304/add-another-logo-in-right-lower-corner-in-the-overleafs-berkeley-theme/648314#648314). Now I need you help again. I'd like that construction to hold for a certain logo (in the right bottom corner) for 3 slides, then change to a different logo for the 3 following slides, (position to remain unchanged in the right bottom corner) and then change again returning to the original logo of the Berkley theme.

[Overleaf Source](https://it.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uc-berkeley-beamer-theme/bywswngntrws)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a meaningful [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and a problem description here. Don't just link to external pages containing the LaTeX code. External links can become invalid or inaccessible, and the question could lose any value to future visitors.

Comment: You can modify `\setbeamertemplate{}` before the 3 frames you like and then revert it back after those 3 frames. It would be easier to answer if you provide a full MWE as @dexteritas said.

Comment: @Zxcvasdf I didn't understand, what is it needed?

Comment: Please have a look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that. It outlines how to provide a minimal working example (MWE).